# How to play m3u8 encrypted playlists by providing key file separately?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, http-live-streaming

I have a `m3u8` playlist file(lets call it prime), which points to another playlist file which in turn has the ts URLs with the key file URL. Using `MPMoviePlayer` I can currently play the `prime m3u8` file. 
The segments are `encrypted` with `AES-128` bit encryption and the key file is in the final `m3u8` file. Is there a way that I can supply the final `m3u8` file and tell the app to use a local key file to decrypt the video, so I don't have to publish the key file publicly.

This is somewhat related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491975/http-live-streaming-with-encryption)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -- You can modify the final m3u8 file before passing it to the player. For example, change the KEY lines to refer to `http://localhost/key`. Then you would want to run a local http server such as cocoahttpserver to deliver the key to the video player.

Comment: I mean is there a way to store the key file locally in the app and not publish it over internet

Comment: @kitwalker Uh, yeah, that's exactly what's described in my answer. It has to be delivered over HTTP, but there's no need to deliver it over the internet.

Comment: Hi doing something similar. Can you guide me how to "change the KEY lines" specifically before passing the the file to the player?

Comment: @JunaidMukhtar You can open a new question on how to modify the text of an HTTP delivered resource on iOS.

Answer (score 8):

I have implemented something similar to this. What we did was:

1. Encrypt each segment of Live stream segment at runtime with a JWT
   Token that has a combination of key value pairs and time stamp for
   validation.
2. Our server knows how to decrypt this key. and when the
       decrypted data is valid, the server responds with a .ts file and
       hence the playback becomes secure.

Here is the complete working code with steps mentioned:

```
//Step 1,2:- Initialise player, change the scheme from http to fakehttp and set delete of resource loader. These both steps will trigger the resource loader delegate function so that we can manually handle the loading of segments. 

func setupPlayer(stream: String) {

operationQ.cancelAllOperations()
let blckOperation = BlockOperation {


    let currentTStamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 + 86400)//
    let timeStamp = String(currentTStamp)
    self.token = JWT.encode(["Expiry": timeStamp],
                            algorithm: .hs256("qwerty".data(using: .utf8)!))

    self.asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: "fake\(stream)")!, options: nil)
    let loader = self.asset?.resourceLoader
    loader?.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    self.asset!.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["playable"], completionHandler: {


        var error: NSError? = nil
        let keyStatus = self.asset!.statusOfValue(forKey: "playable", error: &error)
        if keyStatus == AVKeyValueStatus.failed {
            print("asset status failed reason \(error)")
            return
        }
        if !self.asset!.isPlayable {
            //FIXME: Handle if asset is not playable
            return
        }

        self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: self.asset!)
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
        self.playerView.playerLayer.player = self.player
        self.playerLayer?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)), name: Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.playerItem!)
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "player.currentItem.duration", options: [.new, .initial], context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "player.rate", options: [.new, .old], context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "player.currentItem.status", options: [.new, .initial], context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "player.currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: [.new], context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "player.currentItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: [.new], context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "player.currentItem.playbackBufferEmpty", options: [.new], context: &playerViewControllerKVOContext)
    })
}


operationQ.addOperation(blckOperation)
}

//Step 2, 3:- implement resource loader delegate functions and replace the fakehttp with http so that we can pass this m3u8 stream to the parser to get the current m3u8 in string format.

func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {

var url = loadingRequest.request.url?.absoluteString

let contentRequest = loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest
let dataRequest = loadingRequest.dataRequest
//Check if the it is a content request or data request, we have to check for data request and do the m3u8 file manipulation

if (contentRequest != nil) {

    contentRequest?.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
}
if (dataRequest != nil) {

    //this is data request so processing the url. change the scheme to http

    url = url?.replacingOccurrences(of: "fakehttp", with: "http")

    if (url?.contains(".m3u8"))!
    {

        // do the parsing on background thread to avoid lags
// step 4: 
        self.parsingHandler(url: url!, loadingRequest: loadingRequest, completion: { (success) in

            return true
        })
    }
    else if (url?.contains(".ts"))! {

        let redirect = self.generateRedirectURL(sourceURL: url!)

        if (redirect != nil) {
            //Step 9 and 10:-
            loadingRequest.redirect = redirect!
            let response = HTTPURLResponse(url: URL(string: url!)!, statusCode: 302, httpVersion: nil, headerFields: nil)
            loadingRequest.response = response
            loadingRequest.finishLoading()
        }
        return true
    }
    return true
}
return true
}

func parsingHandler(url: String, loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest, completion:((Bool)->Void)?) -> Void {

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    var string = ""

    var originalURIStrings = [String]()
    var updatedURIStrings = [String]()

    do {

        let model = try M3U8PlaylistModel(url: url)
        if model.masterPlaylist == nil {
            //Step 5:- 
            string = model.mainMediaPl.originalText
            let array = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines)
            if array.count > 0 {

                for line in array {
                    //Step 6:- 
                    if line.contains("EXT-X-KEY:") {

                        //at this point we have the ext-x-key tag line. now tokenize it with , and then
                        let furtherComponents = line.components(separatedBy: ",")

                        for component in furtherComponents {

                            if component.contains("URI") {
                                // Step 7:- 
                                //save orignal URI string to replaced later
                                originalURIStrings.append(component)

                                //now we have the URI
                                //get the string in double quotes

                                var finalString = component.replacingOccurrences(of: "URI=\"", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")

                                finalString = "\"" + finalString + "&token=" + self.token! + "\""
                                finalString = "URI=" + finalString
                                updatedURIStrings.append(finalString)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            if originalURIStrings.count == updatedURIStrings.count {
                //Step 8:- 
                for uriElement in originalURIStrings {

                    string = string.replacingOccurrences(of: uriElement, with: updatedURIStrings[originalURIStrings.index(of: uriElement)!])
                }

                //print("String After replacing URIs \n")
                //print(string)
            }
        }

        else {

            string = model.masterPlaylist.originalText
        }
    }
    catch let error {

        print("Exception encountered")
    }

    loadingRequest.dataRequest?.respond(with: string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    loadingRequest.finishLoading()

    if completion != nil {
        completion!(true)
    }
}
}

func generateRedirectURL(sourceURL: String)-> URLRequest? {

    let redirect = URLRequest(url: URL(string: sourceURL)!)
    return redirect
}
```

1. Implement Asset Resource Loader Delegate for custom handling of streams.
2. Fake the scheme of live stream so that the Resource loader delegate gets called (for normal http/https it doesn't gets called and player tries to handle the stream itself)
3. Replace the Fake Scheme with Http scheme.
4. Pass the stream to M3U8 Parser to get the m3u8 file in plain text format.
5. Parse the plain string to find EXT-X-KEY tags in the current string.
6. Tokenise the EXT-X-KEY line to get to the "URI" method string.
7. Append JWT token separately made, with the current URI method in the m3u8.
8. Replace all instances of URI in the current m3u8 string with the new token appended URI string.
9. Convert this string to NSData format
10. Feed it to the player again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In parsing Handler method not updating loading request url( fakehttp to http in loading request) in m3u8 in Avplayer Swift4 iOS

Comment: can you please help me with this?

Comment: Can you confirm if the stream you are trying to play is not encoded?

Comment: Hi Junaid, I am also facing same issue. Once parsing handler method gets called after that shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource didn't get called. url?.contains(".ts") this condition never execute. Please help me. Thanks