# How to secure HLS videos, with AES 128

Tags: php, ios, web-services, encryption, http-live-streaming

I have to stream videos for mobile devices from server using Http Live Streaming.
the file contains .m3u8 which has listed files of .ts. so how to secure this files to access only authorised users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you could encrypt every chunk with AES-128. AES-128 encrypts the whole chunk with AES using a 128 bit key, Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) and PKCS7 padding. The CBC will be restarted with each segment using the Initialization Vector (IV).

You could do this with ffmpeg by creating a key file that contains the following contents:

```
Key URI
Path to Key File
IV (optional)
```

You could create the key with openssl:

```
openssl rand 16 > video1.key
```

The file would then contain the following contents:

```
http://my-server.com/video1.key
video1.key
```

And then use ffmpeg by providing the path to the key file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -hls_time 6 -hls_key_info_file keyFile playlist.m3u8
```

This will create the segments and a manifest which should contain a #EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI attribute.

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://my-server.com/video1.key"
```

Comment: Note that this is not particularly secure if it's easy to get the key file, e.g. HTTP GET http://my-server.com/video1.key. Look into DRM for better security.

Comment: Any ideas how to secure the key file? Avoiding to HTTP GET my-server.com/video1.key ?

Comment: @PeterTseng Hello, can you explain DRM?

Comment: Generally speaking, DRM protects the key until it reaches the content decryption module on the client device, i.e. other programs cannot access it, in theory. The main DRM options are FairPlay, Widevine, and PlayReady. Generally you choose depending on the devices you want to support. Implementation is complicated, so often companies will pay for a service that handles the DRM.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented similar module securing .ts files with AES-128 encryption and decrypting it on server. Hope this helps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43446800/2429443