# Modify m3u8 file #EXT-X-KEY line dynamically to provide token

Tags: ios, swift, aes, http-live-streaming, m3u8

We are working on encrypting live stream channels with AES-128 Method at runtime on Swift 3.0. The .m3u8 file loaded has the `#EXT-X-KEY` line such as:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://localhost/host/getkey?key=keyfile.key",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000A62
```

I want to modify this at runtime and replace the above line with something like this:

```
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="http://localhost/host/getkey?key=keyfile.key&token=[SOME_CUSTOM_GENERATED_TOKEN]",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000A62
```

**How can I specifically update only this line: `#EXT-X-KEY`?** Im intercepting the URL with delegate callbacks from:
AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest with function callback:

```
- (BOOL) resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest;
```

But different answers to questions suggest rewriting the complete m3u8 file when this is intercepted. which I think is not dynamic and error prone.

Comment: Any luck? I also have the same requirement to modify .m3u8 and .key on run time.

Comment: Have you got this?

Comment: @DeviOS Please check out this link as I have implemented the same and its working great 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43446800/2429443